# Getting error on putting a trailing slash even after trailingSlash: false in Next.js

Tags: next.js, trailing-slash

When I put a trailing slash like [www.example.com/test/](http://www.example.com/test/) I get this error -

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Also I have a page with more subpages, so when I reload the page the trailing slash gets added automatically and this error occurs.

I tried adding trailingSlash: false in my next.config.js file -

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
output: "export",
images: {
unoptimized: true,
},
trailingSlash: false,
};

module. Exports = nextConfig;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.